# Add Loyalty Card to Google Wallet from App

Tags: android, android-pay

I have followed this site, https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/savetowalletnative, that shows how to implement a way to create and save a loyalty card to Google Wallet. It seems the Wallet API does not equal to the sample code they provided in the site.

Has anyone been able to implement this feature in an app?

Thanks!